# Ruby on rails: convert text with html and rails code

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Article in my app has field "body", which contains text with html. For example:

```
<div class ='skill_pic'>
  <img src = "/assets/images/picture_1.png">
</div>
```

In view I call field "body" that:

```
<%= raw @article.body %>
```

In local machine all is ok, but when I deploy my app on production, images don't display right and browser console returns a 404 error.

image_tag in article body can solve my problem, I mean:

```
<div class ='skill_pic'>
  <%= image_tag('images/picture_1.png') %>
</div>
```

But helper raw can't convert text with html and rails method

Now, I think in three directions:

1. find right path for images on production
2. find some helper, which can right convert text with html and rails code
3. find another solution

Answer (score 0):

You could store `erb` partials like this in your database:

```
<div class ='skill_pic'>
  <%= image_tag('images/picture_1.png') %>
</div>
```

And render them with `ERB` in your views:

```
<%= raw ERB.new(@article.body).result(binding) %>
```

Comment: <%= raw ERB.new(@article.body).result(binding) %>

it solve my problem, very big fank you

Comment: Glad I could help. Would you mind accepting the answer when it solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to do some kind of mini-CMS. Be careful not letting users fill in data in your database. You get really bad security problems. If user can edit your html, you better use some kind of templating engine like Liquid or markdown.

That being said, you should just not use the asset pipeline for the referenced images. put the images in the `public` folder instead of the `assets` folder. The public folder will be available like a web root '/', so without the 'public' in the url.